# Angular *ngFor: Display only unique property "category" value and lowest price in each "category"

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor, array-filter

I have an array with objects having "category" & "price" properties among others, in the Angular application I need to display only unique values of "category" property (Example: Economy, Premium & Deluxe) along with the lowest price in that category. I tried filtering it but was unable to achieve it. So can you please help how this can be achieved in Angular? Thank you.

In this example, I need to show:

> **Economy** - Starts from 250USD
>
> **Premium** - Starts from 400USD
>
> **Deluxe** - Starts from 600USD

```
"hotelRooms": [
{
    "price": {
        "total": 250,
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "category": "Economy",
    "subcategory": "single",
},
{
    "price": {
        "total": 350,
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "category": "Economy",
    "subcategory": "double",
},
{
    "price": {
        "total": 450,
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "category": "Economy",
    "subcategory": "family",
},
{
    "price": {
        "total": 400,
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "category": "Premium",
    "subcategory": "single",
},
{
    "price": {
        "total": 500,
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "category": "Premium",
    "subcategory": "double",
},
{
    "price": {
        "total": 600,
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "category": "Deluxe",
    "subcategory": "single",
},
{
    "price": {
       "total": 700,
       "currency": "USD"
    },
    "category": "Deluxe",
    "subcategory": "double",
}
]
```

And in Angular:

```
<div *ngFor="let room of hotelRooms">
    <span class="bold">{{ room.category }}</span> - Starts from {{ room.price.total}}{{ room.price.currency}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand on this question, you need to group by `category` and next get the lowest `price.amount` for each category.

**Concept (TL;DR)**

1. **Group By Category**

   1.1 Create an array for each category if the category array does not exist. Else reuse the created category array.

   1.2 From each category array, find the lowest record based on `price.amount`.

   1.3 If the result (*from 1.2*) return no value (`undefined`), **first reset category array to empty array** and add the `current` record to the category array. **This ensures that each category will only have 1 record with the lowest price.** Else just ignore it.
2. **Data Transformation**

   2.1 Get the item from each category via iterate with key. It will return arrays.

   2.2 Concat multiple arrays (*from 2.1*) into one array.

```js
let groupByCategories = [];

groupByCategories = this.hotelRooms.reduce(function (previous, current) {
  previous[current.category] = previous[current.category] || [];

  let lowest = previous[current.category].find(
    (x) =>
      x.price.total < current.price.total
  );

  if (!lowest) {
    previous[current.category] = [];
    previous[current.category].push(current);
  }

  return previous;
}, Object.create(null));

this.hotelRooms = [].concat(
  ...Object.keys(groupByCategories).map((key) => {
    return groupByCategories[key];
  })
);
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u1zawg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for. Appreciate your time & answer. This alters my original array, can we get a new array out of this?

Comment: Hmmm, if you don't want to **overwrite** the value of `hotelRooms`, then create another variable for it and use it to display in UI. If I did not misunderstand your comment.

Comment: I am facing an issue with this, suppose in that array the last object has a less price may be price:1, Iam getting 2 Deluxe objects. instead of the lowest, same with all. What's the issue?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I just reviewed and fixed the issue. Every time before pushing the record to the category array, you need to reset the category array to an empty array.